# How to shape a div corner in css

Tags: html, css

how to make a div border below corner like in this below image in css.

[image]

Comment: Consider using SVG.

Comment: @WaisKamal can we achieve it through css?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: have you tried border-radius

Comment: @godfather nope border radius will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *hack* using multiple elements like this:

```css
.d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.d2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.wrapper2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #00f;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2"></div>
```